# Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt"

Tags: java, macos, tensorflow, jvm

I'm trying to test out the [DeepLab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) model and I'm having trouble running `bash local_test.sh` inside `research/deeplab`

Here's the error:

```
Uncompressing PascalVOC2012.zip
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

I went into the address and couldn't find any file or folder named `apt` in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/`

[image]
I'm using macOS 10.15, tensorflow 1.15, and python 3.7

I'm new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64707425/java-installation-on-macos-apt-commando-doesnt-work