# Java installation on MacOS: Apt commando doesn't work

Tags: java, macos, puppet

I have installed the latest version of JAVA (jdk-15.0.1_osx-x64_bin.dmg) on a MacBook (Catalina: 10.15.7).

When I try to use JAVA to install PUPPET MASTER with this command:

```
$ sudo apt Puppet Master install
```

I get this message back:

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

Can anybody explain to me what that means and how I can go about installing Puppet Master in my machine?

Thank you so much
Mike

Answer (score 3):

I am not very skilled at doing stuffs in macOS but from what I read this is what I found:

Mac OS X doesn't have apt-get. There is a package manager called [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) that is used instead.

The page I linked to has an up-to-date way of installing homebrew.

After that, usage of Homebrew is `brew install <package>`

One of the prerequisites for Homebrew are the XCode command line tools.

1. Install XCode from the App Store.
2. Follow the directions in this [Stack Overflow answer to install the XCode Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/how-to-install-xcode-command-line-tools).

Answer (score 2):

Puppet supports *agents* running on MacOS, but the *server* is supported only on various flavors of Linux (even though the main server component runs in a JVM).  This is unambiguously stated in [the docs for version 7.0](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.0/server/install_from_packages.html), which is current as of the time of this writing.  It is less clear in the docs of earlier versions, but no less true.

> ```
> Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt"
> ```
>
> (-1)
>
> Can anybody explain to me what that means

It means that there is no program named `apt` in your runtime path, though it looks like you may have a dangling symbolic link to such a program, as otherwise it's unclear why the system would be looking specifically for `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt`.  Note well that `apt` is neither a standard component of OS X nor a standard utility packaged with the JVM.

> and how I can go about
> installing Puppet Master in my machine?

There is no supported way to do this.  It might nevertheless be possible to make it work, but you would probably need to figure it out on your own.  Before you go too far down that path, however, do be sure that you need the master (server) and not just the agent.

Comment: Thanks, John. Even if I couldn't code along, I continued to follow the Google Coursera Course on Automation with Python of which Puppet was a part. I eventually came to understand tat in order for it to work properly I needed the master and ten agent and I decided against installing all this stuff on my 5 year old MacBook.
As for apt, I learned that too in the meantime, and that in Mac OS it is obviously pip the you need to use or pip3. However, I think I made a mess (and that is the reason of the symbolic link I am afraid) all because of this course. 
Thanks again for your help!
Mike

Comment: @MWEsser, `pip` and `pip3` are for installing Python modules only.  OS X does not come standard with any analog of `apt`.

Comment: Thanks again John, I really appreciate it.